# Gnuplot.jl heatmap axis labeling non-uniform grid

Tags: julia, gnuplot, heatmap, axis, colorbar

I have a problem plotting heatmap with log `colorbar` with `Gnuplot.jl`. I currently use the following code

```
using Gnuplot
@gp P_save "w image notit" "set logscale cb"
```

which generates the following figure

[image]

The problem is I need to replace y axis with its real value (using another vector called `Depth`) rather than using index from 0 to 150. And `Depth` has Non-uniform grid.
And do the same for x axis too.

I have looked at these two posts [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18273183/gnuplot-heatmap-axis-labeling) and [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19294342/heatmap-with-gnuplot-on-a-non-uniform-grid). But in my case I don't have external files and data are in variable arrays or vectors.

`P_save` is 150×731 `Matrix{Float64}`, `Depth` is a 150-element `Vector`.

I am very new to both `Gnuplot.jl` and `gnuplot`.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome to SO! In short, you want to combine data from two different arrays – there are several workarounds for that. Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/54314625/4997051

Comment: Do you want the heatmap to look the same, but the Y axis to be different?

Comment: @Bill, Yes! X axis will also be different. Thank you.

Comment: @Eldrad Thank you. Let me take a look at these and get back to you.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. It looks like @Bill 's  comment is what I want. But let me explain more.
I want to plot array 'A=[1,2,3,4; 5, 6, 7, 8; 9, 10, 11, 12]' as a heat map. I want the y axis shows array 'y=[0, -2, -10]' and x axis shows array 'x= [700, 701, 702, 703]' . Is there a way to do that in Julia using Gnuplot.jl. Thank you!

Comment: You probably need something with Xtics and Ytics as in  http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.2/node295.html. I'd leave a full answer to someone who knows gnuplot better